# Using C# Linq ForEach() in F#

Tags: c#, linq, f#, c#-to-f#

I'm translating some code from C# to F#, and I have the following lines that I need to cross over the F#:

```
List<VirtualMachine> vmList = new List<VirtualMachine>();
m_vimClient.FindEntityViews(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, null, null).ForEach(vm => vmList.Add((VirtualMachine)vm));
return vmList;
```

I did the following:

```
let vmList = vimClient.FindEntityViews(typedefof<VirtualMachine>, null, null, null).ForEach(vm => vmList.Add((VirtualMachine)vm))
vmList
```

Unfortunately, Intellisense is telling me that `vm` and `vmList` are not defined in the `ForEach()` part of the F# code.

How would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lambda syntax you used is C# syntax. In F#, a lambda is defined like `fun vm -> …`.

That said, you don't need the `ForEach` at all. The C# version could be written without the lambda as:

```
var vmList = m_vimClient.FindEntityViews(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, null, null)
    .Cast<VirtualMachine>()
    .ToList();
```

In F#, this would be:

```
let vmList = m_vimClient.FindEntityViews(typedefof<VirtualMachine>, null, null, null)
                 |> Seq.cast<VirtualMachine>
                 |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: This isn't quite equivalent, since `Seq.toList` returns an F# `list<_>` (ie. a singly linked list). If you want a `System.Collections.Generic.List<_>` then you can replace the last line with `|> fun s -> new ResizeArray(s)`. Or even just `|> ResizeArray` if you're using the F# 4.0 preview.